# NLog can´t find custom target?

Tags: configuration, config, nlog, target

I have a WinForm C# project where I have added NLog and a custom target. To load this target I have something like this in the NLog config :

```xml
<logger name="GeneralLogger" minlevel="Warn" writeto="customTarget"></logger>

<target name="customTarget" type="LogToService"></target>
```

In the nlog-internal.log I find this :

> 2020-05-12 11:48:16.0083 Warn Error has been raised. Exception:
>   NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Failed to create target type:
>   LogToService ---> System.ArgumentException: Target cannot be found:
>   'LogToService'    at NLog.Config.Factory`2.CreateInstance(String
>   itemName)    at
>   NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.CreateTargetType(String
>   targetTypeName)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I have seen suggestions on adding extensions with assembly but the custom target is in the same project as where I added the NLog Nuget?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it isn't in a separate assembly, you could do this:

```cs
// NLog 4.7+
NLog.LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(s =>
   s.RegisterTarget<MyNamespace.LogToService>("LogToService")
);
```

or this in the nlog.config (before `<targets>`:

```xml
  <extensions> 
    <add assembly="YourAssembly"/> 
  </extensions>
```

For all options, see [Register your custom component](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Register-your-custom-component)